# C# WPF add character to textbox without binding

Tags: c#, binding, textbox

Can i **simply** add characters without binding this characters to my ViewModel? 
I need these to show physical units like *cm*, *mm*, *m*, *cm^3*, ...

XAML:

```
<TextBox 
Text="{Binding value_top}" //sth. like + "cm"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="50"/>
```

VW:

```
value_top = 22.9
```

Output aim:

```
22.9 cm
```

I know, I can overlay a Label, but i would like to know if there is another possibility.

Comment: do you mean like string interpolation

Comment: Do you need the binding to be two-way? So the user can update the value in the textbox? Or is one-way acceptable?

Comment: two way, that's the problem. I can't do it as @OmegaMan would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a converter which will take the double and return a string. Here is an untested example to get you started:

```
public class DoubleToString: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dbl = (double) value;

        return $"{dbl} cm";           
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Double.Parse(Regex.Match(value.ToString(), "[\d.]+").Value);    
    }
}
```